# LocSvc error messages in logcat

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

After various Google searches, I've come up short for an answer, so:

I've written a delivery tracking application that our drivers take with them on LG G2 devices. It uses XMPP to converse with HQ and upload information, as well as tracks our vehicles by use of GPS. Today, all of a sudden all tracking stopped. Each of our devices thought they were at base all day... Bit odd, I thought, no new software pushed into production for a month or so. So I get given a device from one of our drivers and plug it in to Eclipse to see what its doing and LogCat is FULL of this:

```
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_api_v02(955): V/locClientSendReq:2413] qmi_client_send_msg_sync returned 0
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_api_v02(955): V/convertQmiResponseToLocStatus:681]: result = 0, error = -6564, status = 0
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_api_v02(955): V/loc_sync_send_req:512]: select_id = 0,locClientSendReq returned 0
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_api_v02(955): D/loc_free_slot:299]: freeing slot 0
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_api_v02(955): V/loc_sync_send_req:539]: success (select id 0)
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ApiV02(955): D/Got Zpp fix location validity (lat:1, lon:1, timestamp:1 accuracy:1)
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ApiV02(955): D/(50.9496151, -2.6051965), timestamp 1409153485700, accuracy 3168.393066
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955): V/creating msg ULP_MSG_REPORT_POSITION
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955): V/creating msg ox60b
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955): V/flags: 63
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955):   source: 4
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955):   latitude: 50.949615
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955):   longitude: -2.605197
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955):   altitude: 94.844193
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955):   speed: 6.000000
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955):   bearing: 0.712935
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955):   accuracy: 3168.393066
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955):   timestamp: 1409153485700
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955):   rawDataSize: 0
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955):   rawData: 0x0
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955):   Session status: 0
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955):  Technology mask: 1
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_utils_q(955): D/msg_q_snd: Sending message with handle = 0x735B4310
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_utils_ll(955): D/linked_list_add: Adding to list data_obj = 0x735B4310
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_utils_q(955): D/msg_q_snd: Finished Sending message with handle = 0x735B4310
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_eng(955): V/Exiting int loc_eng_get_zpp_handler(loc_eng_data_s_type&) line 2044 0
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_MsgTask(955): D/MsgTask::loop() 701679 listening ...
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_utils_q(955): D/msg_q_rcv: Waiting on message
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_libulp(955): I/===> int ulp_msg_process_start_req() line 414 
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_libulp(955): I/int ulp_msg_process_start_req(), at ulp state = 1
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_libulp(955): V/Exiting int ulp_msg_process_start_req() line 459 -1
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_libulp(955): V/Exiting int ulp_msg_process_system_update(UlpSystemEvent) line 1398 0
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_ulp_log(955): V/deleting msg UNKNOWN (0x60e)
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_utils_q(955): D/msg_q_rcv: Waiting on message
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_utils_ll(955): D/linked_list_remove: Removing from list
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_utils_q(955): D/msg_q_rcv: Received message 0x735B4310 rv = 0
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_libulp(955): D/void ulp_msg_main(void*) received msg of type: 0x60b
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_libulp(955): I/===> int ulp_brain_process_zpp_position_report(loc_sess_status, LocPosTechMask, const UlpLocation*) line 1427 
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_libulp(955): I/int ulp_brain_process_zpp_position_report(loc_sess_status, LocPosTechMask, const UlpLocation*), zpp session status = 0, source: 4, flags = 0x3f, lat = 50.949615, lon = -2.605197, uncertainty = 3168.393066, tech_mask = 0x1
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_libulp(955): I/===> bool ulp_zpp_engine_running() line 62 
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_libulp(955): V/Exiting bool ulp_zpp_engine_running() line 73 1
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_libulp(955): I/int ulp_brain_process_zpp_position_report(loc_sess_status, LocPosTechMask, const UlpLocation*), first_fix_pending 1, request active = 1,zpp running 1, zpp state 1 
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_libulp(955): I/===> int ulp_msg_send_generic_position_report(loc_sess_status, LocPosTechMask, const UlpLocation*, const GpsLocationExtended*, const void*) line 942 
08-27 16:31:24.944: D/Ulp_jni(955): Location CB invoked
```

Is this anything to worry about? I'm particularly interested in "error = -6564" here:

```
08-27 16:31:24.944: E/LocSvc_api_v02(955): V/convertQmiResponseToLocStatus:681]: result = 0, error = -6564, status = 0
```

Which I've tried to search google for, but to no avail. Any help is very much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They marked as obsolete https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62285
I don't know why. The issue is still happening on my gs4.
With that ton of messages is really hard to debug my applications, since the logcat overflow quickly. I'm very concerned about battery drain.

Answer (score 1):

This seems an obvious misclassification of a debug as an error
message.

I asked today for a clarification in which version of Android
the bug was fixed, will post here as soon as I get a reply.

I'm seeing the same problem with hundreds of these per second
on Android 4.4.2.  Battery drain is certainly a concern here.

Comment: No update from Google after a year... https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62285